# Android studio 3.6 can`t open emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, android-studio-3.6

**Background:**

I am using android studio 3.6 as my IDE for flutter development, the problem below only happening when I use android studio with flutter, **in native android development it's all fine**.

**The problem:**

Sometimes my android studio will not be able to detect my emulator and in order to run something on it(or even open it), I will need to open the Avd manager and run it from there (It is working sometimes).

### Visual explanation:

1) **What I meant by** `will not be able to detect my emulator...` looks like this:

[image]

2) **And What I meant by** *I need to open the Avd manager and run it from there* looks like this:

[image]

### **Question:**

I am using the stable version of android studio, why this is happening and can I make sure that android studio will detect the emulator every time without going to the Avd manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the android studio to 3.6.3 version solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had this probelem too.
You can update android studio plugins if any update is required.
Then, please uninstall android studio and install again.
This worked for me.